# Как в рантайме привести строку к нужному типу?

Tags: java, рефлексия

Есть класс

```
public class A {
  public Integer field;
}
```

Как в рантайме присвоить полю приведённое к нужному типу значение строки типа такого:

```
A a = new A();
String field = "field";
String value = "123";
a.getClass().getField(field).set(a, /*value*/ ); // КАК?!
```

Comment: А зачем его в строке хранить?

Comment: @Qwertiy такое апи, что ж поделать

Comment: @post_zeew да, но нужно для любого типа поля привести к нужному типу поля (хотя бы для простых типов)

Comment: Решение со `switch` по типу поля устроит?

Comment: @post_zeew по другому никак?

Comment: @gwgw, Может и можно, но на ум ничего другого не приходит. Какой вопрос – такой ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно вот так

```
A a = new A();
String fieldName = "field";
String fieldValue = "123";
// берем поле
Field field = a.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
// берем класс поля
Class fieldType = field.getType();
// ищем конструктор с параметром типа String
Constructor constructor = fieldType.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class);
// делаем новый объект
Object value = constructor.newInstance(fieldValue);
field.set(a, value);
System.out.println(a.field);
```

Comment: Возможно, из вопроса неясно, но зачем мне использовать рефлексию, если я знаю тип поля? Поле может быть любого типа, т.е. нужно привести в рантайме

Comment: совсем любого? и преобразовывается всегда из строки?

Comment: всегда из строки. Можно только для тех у кого есть нужный `parse` типа обёрток для примитивных типов хотя бы

Comment: @gwgw я изменил код. Для большинства оберток будет работать.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по [этому вопросу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127318/java-how-can-i-do-dynamic-casting-of-a-variable-from-one-type-to-another) и одному из ответов на него:

> the only way to solve this in Java is to write code that covers all cases with lots of `if` and `else` and `instanceof` expressions

какой-то *хороший* способ найти вряд ли получится.

Самое примитивное решение:

```
A a = new A();
String field = "field";
String value = "123";

Field targetField = a.getClass().getField(field);
String targetFieldType = targetField.getType().getSimpleName();

switch (targetFieldType) {
    case "Integer":
    case "int":
        targetField.set(a, Integer.parseInt(value));
        break;
    case "String":
        targetField.set(a, value);
        break;
}
```

Comment: это печально, зря мучался значэт, спасибо